# "Please install the sqlite3 package manually on startup." -error on executable startup

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm using Electron Forge with SQLite3. In development, everything works fine (rebuilding and then starting the app, since SQLite needs to be recompiled).

```
electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3
electron-forge start
```

However, when I build and then run the executable (Windows) created with :

`electron-forge publish`

I get :

> Please install the sqlite3 package manually on startup.

I've already added sqlite3 as external to the webpack config, but no luck.

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  entry: './electron/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: require('./rules.webpack'),
  },
  externals: ['sqlite3'],
}
```

better-sqlite3 is not an option since I'm using Sequelize too.